# Secure REST Api with Spring boot and JWT

Tags: java, spring, rest, jwt

I'm trying to secure my REST server with `JWT` which I have implemented my self (Meaning that no spring stuff in the JWT handling it self, everything else is `Spring` of course).

I have this class: `JWTToken implements Authentication`.

I have a filter that is responsible of setting the `JWTToken` instance at the `SecurityContextHolder`:

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
public void doFilter(...) {
     ....
     JWTToken token = new JWTToken(jwt); // this init the Authentication object with all the jwt claims
     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
     ....
}
```

I also have a resource for debugging this:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/protected_resource",
        method = RequestMethod.POST
)
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public RESTResponse<String> debugJwt() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); // here I can see that the context is the right one
    return new RESTResponse<>("This was successful", "feedback message", true);
}
```

I am missing one peace of the puzzle which I could not found in any of the resources online and this is how to implement `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and specifically the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` metohd.

When I tried do this, for instance:

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Requests did not pass through this and the resource was not getting called.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `JWTToken` class should implement the method:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

The implementation should return a collection of the user granted roles, one of them will be the "admin" role, something like:

```
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin"));
}
```

Of course in your case you will query the DB or the JWT token and parse the user roles.